# Conflicting Python Installs in OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I've got myself in a pickle and would like some guidance before my laptop suffers GBH.

I have been using my Macbook for a few years without probs but when I got a new iMac at work I noticed everyone recommended useing homebrew for new Python installs (esp. on Mavericks).

Now my laptop has worked fine with the original Python. But I decided to try and do it the new homebrew way (its now Mavericks btw).

First I clear out Mavericks due to some other conflict then reinstall a fresh. Get nginx, php-fpm, mysql, etc working.

Now Python.

I can use pip to install packages. But when I try

`workon myproject`

I get:

`/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
/usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper`

But then it switches to that virtualenv anyway - but not the directory that the project is in!

When I run `where python` I get several entries:

`/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python`

I've tried fiddling with my path but keep getting other errors that all seem to indicate my two Python installations are conflicting badly. Is there a simple solution or do I need to wipe out hombrew and start again from the beginning? Or just give up on homebrew and use OSX built in?

To clarify my current $PATH is:
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/op‌​t/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/me/Development/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/me/Dev‌​elopment/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was an unusual one but here goes:

In my `.zshrc` file I had the following layout:

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="steeef"
plugins=(osx virtualenv virtualenvwrapper python github)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
# various aliases
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

The problem was the Oh My ZSH plugin *virtualenvwrapper* was looking in the default python path location as the custom path had yet to be set later in the `.zshrc` file.

The solution therefore was to move the PATH declaration before the plugins like so:

```
ZSH_THEME="steeef"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
plugins=(osx virtualenv virtualenvwrapper python github)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
# various aliases
```

Now the ZSH plugins are referencing the correct Python install and therefore the correct Python packages path.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your preferred version earlier in your PATH variable. So if you want to use `/usr/local/bin/python`, from the command line you could modify your PATH by `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/python:$PATH`. See here for more info: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/

Comment: I already do. My current path is: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH` and the output of echo'ing my `$PATH` variable is: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Users/me/Development/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/me/Development/Android/sdk/platform-tools`